# Scan on DynamDB table or Query on secondary global index or a local index (What's the best solution)

Tags: performance, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, query-performance, nosql

I have AWS DynamoDB table called "Users", whose hash key/primary key is "UserID" which consist of emails. It has two attributes, first called "Daily Points" and second "TimeSpendInTheApp". Now I need to run a query or scan on the table, that will give me top 50 users which have the highest points and top 50 users which have spend the most time in the app. Now this query will be executed only once a day by cron aws lambda. I am trying to find the best solutions for this query or scan. For me, the cost is most important than speed/or efficiency. As maintaining secondary global index or a local index on points can be costly operations, as I have to assign Read and Write units for those indexes, which I want to avoid.  "Users" table will have a maximum of 100,000 to 150,000 records and on average it will have 50,000 records. What are my best options? Please suggest.

I am thinking, my first option is, I can scan the whole table on Filter Expression for records above certain points (5000 for example), after this scan, if 50 or more than 50 records are found, then simply sort the values and take the top 50 records. If this scan returns no or very less results then reduce the Filter Expression value (3000 for example), then again do the same scan operation. If Filter Expression value (2500 for example) returns too many records, like 5000 or more, then reduce the Filter Expression value. Is this even possible, I guess it would also need to handle pagination. Is it advisable to scan on a table which has 50,000 record?

Any advice or suggestion will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, creating indexes for the above use case doesn't simplify the process as it doesn't have solution for aggregation or sorting.

I would export the data to HIVE and run the queries rather than writing code to determine the result especially as it is going to be a batch executed only once per day.

**Something like below:-**

**Create Hive table:-**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hive_users(userId string, dailyPoints bigint, timeSpendInTheApp bigint) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "Users",
"dynamodb.column.mapping" = "userId:UserID,dailyPoints:Daily_Points,timeSpendInTheApp:TimeSpendInTheApp");
```

**Queries:-**

```
SELECT dailyPoints, userId from hive_users sort by dailyPoints desc;
SELECT timeSpendInTheApp, userId from hive_users sort by timeSpendInTheApp desc;
```

[Hive Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/EMR_Interactive_Hive.html)